# Executable to generate a system (basic hardware/software configuration) report on Windows?

Tags: directx, hardware

A lot of our customers report strange problems with our software, which is a 2D game using DirectX. The problems reported are often vague due to the nature of our clientele (which does not know how to make good bug reports or what information to provide).

We have not been able to replicate these problems even though a significant portion of our client base reports them.

We are looking for a way to generate a report (basically just a text file) with basic system information: hardware like graphics card, processor, memory, manufacturer; and software like OS version, anti-virus software in use, DirectX versions, etc. We would then have them send us this report file.

We have looked at using [msinfo32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300887) but the switches to limit it to certain categories do not work for us on our test computers, and we do not want all of the information it provides.

edit: msinfo32 no longer supports some of the switches we need to use on Windows 7.

Comment: EasyInfo, which is used by electronic arts. If you want preinstalled software, you're out of luck, I think - you'll have to either write your own tool or use systeminfo, dxcapsviewer, crash dumps and registry snapshots.

Comment: Also, thinking about it, some time ago there was some software that was supposed to be a "successor of aida32", and it might provide information you're looking for. You could unpack into single folder from zip without "installing" it. I'm not sure if it is still available, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look in to [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy), as it can create such a report. Once run, the user simply has to choose File>Save as Text file to generate a text file of all hardware, though not software and A/V.

Comment: Speccy requires them to install something, which we can't do. Ideally it's a command-line tool already on the system, or a single executable (comparable to HijackThis or so).

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but figured it couldn't hurt to suggest it. You could have them download the portable version?
http://www.piriform.com/speccy/builds